# How to serialize a selected HTML element into a string?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to serialize an entire HTML tag into a string which I selected using the `this` keyword in the HTML tag.

Example:

```html
<button id="3" onClick="print(this)">B3</button>  
<script type="text/javascript">
  function print(element)
  {
      console.log(element);
      var x = element.toString()
      console.log(x)
  }
</script>
```

When we check the first `console.log` statement, the result will be:

```html
<button id="3" onClick="print(this)">B3</button>
```

In the second `console.log` statement, the result will be:

```
[object HTMLButtonElement]
```

Is there any way I can serialize the tag into string like:

```js
"<button id="3" onClick="print(this)">B3</button>"
```

Comment: Try `element.outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the node to a [`new XMLSerializer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) like so:

```js
function print(element)
{
    console.log(element);
    var x = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element);
    console.log(x)
}
```

```html
<button id="3" onClick="print(this)">B3</button>
```

Output:

```
<button id="3" onclick="print(this)">B3</button>
<button xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="3" onclick="print(this)">B3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute of the element, which will return the full HTML for that element as shown below:

```js
function print(element) {
  var s = element.outerHTML;
  console.log(typeof(s));
  console.log(s);

  var t = element;
  console.log(typeof(t));
  console.log(t);
}
```

```html
<button id="3" onClick="print(this)">B3</button>
```

Variable `s` is set to the `outerHTML` property which is a `string`.

Variable `t` uses the original code you posted that just used `element` which is an object.  I've added `typeof` so you can see that `s` is a `string` as requested.